# Maximum number of edges with k components

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given $N$ vertices and $K$ components what is the maximum number of edges that may exists ? I just got gut instinct that it will be maximum if we take one set with $k-1$ vertices and this will have no edges. And other set with $N-K+1$ vertices which will be a complete graph. And yes it is the right answer $(N-k+1)(N-k)/2$. But I am not confident in my approach. I know its correct but not a formal proof. I want to know is there any solution which answers the question with more mathematical approach.

Comment: You can use the fact that $(a+b)^2 \geq a^2 + b^2$  for $K=2$ components and see how to adapt that for $K > 2$ too.

Comment: @jjohnThanks , I also came to know about other way that , if I consider a complete graph with n vertices $n(n-1)/2$ edges. Now make two components by separating a vertex by after removing n-1 edges. Again make other vertex a separate component by deleting n-2 edges this time. Likewise we get n(n-1)/2 - ( (n-1) + (n-2) +..+ (n-k+1))